# How can I fix the error Undefined variable: _ENV in /home/nginx/domains/mydomain.com/system/Config/BaseConfig.php?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi, environment-variables, codeigniter

I am trying to install a Codeigniter application in pure NGINX + PHP-FPM environment but it was previously developed in apache .

After adding all the proper rules to Nginx in order to work with Codeigniter I am being faced with this error related to my $_ENV variable .

```
Undefined variable: _ENV in /home/nginx/domains/mydomain.com/system/Config/BaseConfig.php ?
```

Here is the code calling the $_ENV variable :

```
case array_key_exists("{$shortPrefix}.{$property}", $_ENV):
                            return $_ENV["{$shortPrefix}.{$property}"];
                            break;
                    case array_key_exists("{$shortPrefix}.{$property}", $_SERVER):
                            return $_SERVER["{$shortPrefix}.{$property}"];
```

Worth mentioning I am trying to call a task by running php spark task:run tasks when the error takes place in CLI .

Things I have tried to do so far :

1) I have added a _ENV variable to my PHP-FPM this way :

```
env[_ENV] = production
```

2) I exported ENV variable in CLI :

```
export _ENV=production
```

3) I have added the following line in Nginx Config :

```
location / {

  fastcgi_param CI_ENV  production;

}
```

Nothing seems to work and my $_ENV or $SERVER variables always seem empty and I get the same error when I try to run my task .

Anything else I can make to debug this and setup my $_ENV variable to run properly with my app ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution !

Changing the default of this variable in PHP.INI to off did the trick !

```
auto_globals_jit = Off
```

Comment: [`auto_globals_jit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-globals-jit) should have no effect for your case. The warning in the docs does mention basically that if it's `on` *and* you're using variable variable to refer to `$_ENV`, then it won't be initialized. But you're clearly using `$_ENV` reference in your code. You likely had it "fixed" by `export _ENV=production` alone.